# Необъяснимо большой размер базы в postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Не могу понять, почему общий размер базы данных в postgresql в три раза превышаем сумму размеров всех таблиц и индексов этой базы.

Вот общий размер БД - 62 Гб:

```
5620sam=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('5620sam'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 62 GB
(1 row)
```

Но при этом запрос, который выводит все таблицы и индексы, в сумме дает около 18 Гб:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) AS indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        pg_table_size(table_name) AS table_size,
        pg_indexes_size(table_name) AS indexes_size,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
    ) AS all_tables
    ORDER BY total_size DESC
) AS pretty_sizes;

                          table_name                          | table_size | indexes_size | total_size
--------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+------------
 "public"."dot3"                                              | 2435 MB    | 1402 MB      | 3837 MB
 "public"."sapbasestats"                                      | 2266 MB    | 576 MB       | 2842 MB
 "public"."omniports"                                         | 1573 MB    | 1172 MB      | 2746 MB
 "public"."ddm"                                               | 999 MB     | 715 MB       | 1714 MB
 "public"."intaddstats"                                       | 787 MB     | 422 MB       | 1209 MB
 "public"."omnidrops"                                         | 747 MB     | 405 MB       | 1152 MB
 "public"."umtstwamp"                                         | 525 MB     | 369 MB       | 894 MB
 "public"."umtstwampdays"                                     | 223 MB     | 185 MB       | 408 MB
 "public"."umtshsdpa"                                         | 199 MB     | 159 MB       | 358 MB
 "public"."dot3_report"                                       | 229 MB     | 22 MB        | 251 MB
 "public"."umtshsdpadays"                                     | 103 MB     | 82 MB        | 185 MB
 "public"."alarmshistory"                                     | 103 MB     | 63 MB        | 166 MB
 "public"."cem_report"                                        | 49 MB      | 8728 kB      | 57 MB
 "public"."omnifdb"                                           | 23 MB      | 12 MB        | 35 MB
 "public"."port_utilization"                                  | 17 MB      | 5184 kB      | 22 MB
 "public"."spokes"                                            | 14 MB      | 3328 kB      | 18 MB
 "public"."ports"                                             | 13 MB      | 1880 kB      | 15 MB
 "public"."fabric_report"                                     | 8968 kB    | 2760 kB      | 11 MB
 "public"."lsphops"                                           | 7600 kB    | 2504 kB      | 10104 kB
 "public"."arpvprn"                                           | 2768 kB    | 3720 kB      | 6488 kB
<далее таблицы с незначительным total_size в несколько Кб>
```

Соответственно, вопрос, а куда делись еще 40 Гб? VACUUM FULL делаю каждый день, сейчас также сделал, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Посмотрите ещё размеры таблиц pg_catalog'а. А то вдруг вы large object пользуетесь или ещё чем. И зачем vacuum full делать каждый день?

Comment: Проверил схему pg_catalog, там все таблицы маленькие, самая большая - "pg_catalog"."pg_depend" 1,1 Мб. VACUUM FULL делается каждую ночь, потому что ночью БД без нагрузки и это простой способ почистить все пустые кортежи и освободить память на дисках.

Comment: а `du` и `du --apparent-size` что говорят? может postgre выдаёт размер файлов включая дыры?

Comment: Размер фалов по du совпадает с размером БД, который выдает SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('5620sam'));. Сейчас это соответственно:

`du --apparent-size -h /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
...
73G     /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/`

`postgres=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('5620sam'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 71 GB
(1 row)
`